# Capitalize every first word except some

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to capitalize first character of all words in string.

> Condition 1. there are some excluded words like: `'of', 'the'` which should not 
>   Condition 2. Those excluded world should not be first in string.

Here's my code:

```js
const movieTitleFormatter = title => {
  if(!title) {
    return '';
  }
  let arr = [];
  let exludeWords = ['of', 'the']
  arr = title.split(' ');
  return arr.map(word =>
  {
     return exludeWords.includes(word) ? [word] : word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);

  }).join(' ');
}

console.log(movieTitleFormatter('psycho')); //'Psycho';
console.log(movieTitleFormatter('silence of the lambs')); //'Silence of the Lambs';
console.log(movieTitleFormatter('the last emperor')); //'The Last Emperor'; //Here is shows wrong.
console.log(movieTitleFormatter()); //'';
```

I did above one but, couldn't find way to except first word. Or any other best way to get result?

Comment: Just as a curiosity regarding truthy/falsy: you have 3 answers so far suggesting `&& i !== 0`. It can be just `&& i`, since all indices except 0 are truthy.

Comment: You are right. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add another condition to check the *index* of the word:

```js
const movieTitleFormatter = title => {
  if(!title) {
    return '';
  }
  let arr = [];
  let exludeWords = ['of', 'the']
  arr = title.split(' ');
  return arr.map((word, i) =>
  {
     return exludeWords.includes(word) && i!=0 ? [word] : word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);

  }).join(' ');
}

console.log(movieTitleFormatter('psycho')); //'Psycho';
console.log(movieTitleFormatter('silence of the lambs')); //'Silence of the Lambs';
console.log(movieTitleFormatter('the last emperor')); //'The Last Emperor'; //Here is shows wrong.
console.log(movieTitleFormatter()); //'';
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative approach using the `.replace()` method with a replacement function as the second argument. The regular expression matches all strings of word characters separated by word-boundaries and capitalizes them based on whether it is or isn't in the `exludeWords` array:

```js
const cap = str => str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
const movieTitleFormatter = (title = '') => {
  const exludeWords = ['of', 'the']
  return cap(
    title.replace(/\b\w+\b/g, m => exludeWords.includes(m) ? m : cap(m))
  );
}

console.log(movieTitleFormatter('psycho')); // 'Psycho';
console.log(movieTitleFormatter('silence of the lambs')); // 'Silence of the Lambs';
console.log(movieTitleFormatter('the last emperor')); // 'The Last Emperor'; 
console.log(movieTitleFormatter()); // '';
```

Comment: Thank You Nick.  How would you fix this one to only place upper case on first character:  console.log(movieTitleFormatter('tesTing onE twO'));

Answer (score 0):

Capitalise first word's first character before `forEach()`

```js
const movieTitleFormatter = title => {
  if(!title) {
    return '';
  }
  let arr = [];
  let exludeWords = ['of', 'the']
  arr = title.split(' ');
  arr[0] = arr[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[0].slice(1);
  return arr.map(word =>
  {
     return exludeWords.includes(word) ? [word] : word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);

  }).join(' ');
}

console.log(movieTitleFormatter('psycho')); //'Psycho';
console.log(movieTitleFormatter('silence of the lambs')); //'Silence of the Lambs';
console.log(movieTitleFormatter('the last emperor')); //'The Last Emperor'; //Here is shows wrong.
console.log(movieTitleFormatter());
```

Comment: Is there a problem with this approach? Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

The `map` method has a second parameter which carries the index of the element in the array. Knowing this you can use the following

```js
let  movieTitleFormatter = title => {
  if(!title) {
    return '';
  }
  let arr = [];
  let exludeWords = ['of', 'the']
  arr = title.split(' ');
  return arr.map((word, index) =>
  {
     return exludeWords.includes(word) && index !=0 ? [word] : word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);

  }).join(' ');
}

console.log(movieTitleFormatter('the last emperor')); //'The Last Emperor'; //Here is shows wrong.
console.log(movieTitleFormatter('silence of the lambs')); //'Silence of the Lambs';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is incomplete. You are excluding the word even if it's the first word of the sentence. You need to check the index of the word. 
When using map you can add the optional index parameter:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax

```js
const movieTitleFormatter = title => {
  if(!title) {
    return '';
  }
  let arr = [];
  let exludeWords = ['of', 'the']
  arr = title.split(' ');
  return arr.map((word,idx) =>
  {
     return (exludeWords.includes(word) && idx !==0) ? [word] : word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);

  }).join(' ');
}

console.log(movieTitleFormatter('psycho')); //'Psycho';
console.log(movieTitleFormatter('silence of the lambs')); //'Silence of the Lambs';
console.log(movieTitleFormatter('the last emperor')); //'The Last Emperor'; //Here is shows wrong.
console.log(movieTitleFormatter()); //'';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to turn `'the last emperor'` to `'The Last Emperor'` and not to `'the Last Emperor'`, I would suggest you to add the second parameter of map, which is the index (for further info see [MDNs docu about Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) because then you could simply add a check whether it is the first position or not.

Your snippet would then look like this:

```
const movieTitleFormatter = title => {
  if(!title) {
    return '';
  }
  let arr = [];
  let excludeWords = ['of', 'the']
  arr = title.split(' ');
  return arr.map((word, i) =>
  {
     return excludeWords.includes(word) && i > 0 ? [word] : word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);

  }).join(' ');
}

console.log(movieTitleFormatter('psycho'));
console.log(movieTitleFormatter('silence of the lambs'));
console.log(movieTitleFormatter('the last emperor'));
console.log(movieTitleFormatter());
```

This should do what you want it to do, but I'd recommend using [RegEx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version:

```
function movieTitleFormatter(str)
{
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b(?!(?!^)(?:of|the)\b)([a-z])/g, m => m.toUpperCase());
}

console.log(movieTitleFormatter('psycho')); //'Psycho';
```